magit - is there a way to highlight changes from a pull request in-line, while still allowing code navigation?
When I use magit-diff-range, it shows the result in a separate buffer.
Unfortunately, code navigation is not available in the diff buffer.
With magit-blame, I can see the blames, and I'm still able to do code navigation.
Is there a way to get a blame-style diff, where I can see the changes for the pull request highlighted in-line in the code and still allow us to do the code navigation?
Or as an alternative, magit-blame-like feature that shows blame tags NOT for every commit, but only tags changes introduced by the pull request as a whole?

I found that I can use diff-hl to do something similar.
I can do git reset <commit>, and diff-hl will show unmerged changes in the fringe.

As OP found out, one can use the diff-hl package to do something similar.
